# Java parameterize class warning

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I want to parametirize class with two other params, so that I can provide one of them independently, AdGroupIdentifier OR KeywordIdentifier.  But I am getting following warning: `The type parameter KeywordIdentifier is hiding the type KeywordIdentifier.`

Do you think I am doing something wrong? What is a correct way of doing that?

Thanks for any help!

```
public class Metrics <T extends AdGroupIdentifier, KeywordIdentifier> {

    public void addMetric(T identifier){ .... }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have class named `KeywordIdentifier`. The class parameter named `KeywordIdentifier` does not relate to class with the same name but can confuse humans. This is exactly what the compilation warning mean.

BTW according to naming convention you should tend to call type parameter using one (or maximum 2) capital letter. In your case change the class definition to

```
public class Metrics <T extends AdGroupIdentifier, K>
```

or, if you want the seconds parameter to extend class `KeywordIdentifier`:

```
public class Metrics <T extends AdGroupIdentifier, K extends KeywordIdentifier>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the KeywordIdentifier. It seems that AdGroupIdentifier implements or extends KeywordIdentifier:

```
    public class Metrics <T extends AdGroupIdentifier> {

        public void addMetric(T identifier){ .... }

    }
```

Comment: +1 I agree, just removed it as it doesn't appear it is needed or used.

Answer (score 0):

Normally generic types are given one letter names as they are parameterized.

The way you have it, you might confuse `KeywordIndetifier` which extends `Object` with your class `KeywordIdentifer` and while they have the same name, they are not related.